# print a matched line and the following line

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file with contents like

```
//DCOM/PC/dev/R2.0.0_OZ99163/site-config/profile.cfg
... #2 change 1101417 delete on 2015/06/15 by SMukherj
... #1 change 1099558 branch on 2015/06/08 by BaDas@PC_win_R1.1 (xtext) 'OZ 97960: Startup modifications'
... ... branch from //DCOM/PC/dev/R2.0.0_OZ99163/site-config/profile.cfg#1,#2
```

Steps:

1. Search for the pattern `//`
2. Print the matched line and the line below it (I only want the next line immediately following).
3. Now I want to print file name e.g `profile.cfg, revision - #2 , name SMukherj`

This is what I have tried but I'm not able to proceed further:

```
grep -i '\/\/' -A1 test.txt | grep -v '\.\.\. \.\.\.' | awk -F'@' '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Just so we're clear, can you please include expected output that matches your sample input?

Answer (score 4):

This does the job using just `awk`:

```
awk -F '[/ ]'  '/^\/\// { file = $NF; getline; print file, $2, $NF; }'
```

Split the fields on slashes or spaces.  If the line starts with `//`, then save the last field as `file`; read the next line; print the file, the second field (the version number), and the last field (the user name).

On three copies of your input data, it produces:

```
profile.cfg #2 SMukherj
profile.cfg #2 SMukherj
profile.cfg #2 SMukherj
```

Comment: Dang. It doesn't get much shorter than this.  OH!  You could use single-character variables!  Bam!  ;-)

Comment: @ghoti: I used quite a lot of spaces too :)

Comment: The use of `^//` for the regex is probably an improvement over the original, but rests on the assumption that all lines which match this regex (and none others) are interesting. With only a single example record, it's hard to know whether you can make these generalizations.

Comment: @tripleee: The only significance of the three repeats is that it shows that the extra lines after the `//` and the following line are duly ignored.  Without more data, it is impossible to do a better job — there isn't enough information, as you say.  Even one extra record would give me greater confidence.  I'm not sure whether I trust the `...` parts either, but the information in the question is all there is to go on.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use `sed` or `awk` for something like this. *JonathanLeffler* showed you how to do it with `awk`, here is a similar solution using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^\/\// { s:.*/::; N; s/\n.* / /p; }' test.txt
```

Output:

```
profile.cfg SMukherj
```

#### Explanation

Here is a commented version of the above.

*parse.sed*

```sed
/^\/\// {            # Run code-block on lines starting with double-slash (//)
  s:.*/::            # Remove everything up-to the last slash (/)
  N                  # Add next line to pattern-space
  s/\n.* / /p        # Substitute everything from the first new-line to
                     # the last space with a space and print pattern-space
}
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -nf parse.sed test.txt
```

Comment: And if the address regexp is a bit daunting, you can use `_` (or other character) as its delimiter: `\_//_`\